# Replacing old content of a text file with new content when we write the file second time

Tags: java

Hi I am writing some data  to a text file through java code but when i again run the code its again appending to the older data ,i want the new data to overwrite the older version.
can any one help..

```
BufferedWriter  out1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("inValues.txt" , true));
  for(String key: inout.keySet())
                {
                    String val = inout.get(key);
                    out1.write(key+" , "+val+"\n");
                }
                out1.close();
```

Comment: Interesting, the usual scenery is new data is overwriting old data while programmers want it appending.

Answer (score 5):

code would help, but its likely you are telling it to append the data since the default is to overwrite. find something like:

```
file = new FileWriter("outfile.txt", true);
```

and change it to

```
file = new FileWriter("outfile.txt", false);
```

or just

```
file = new FileWriter("outfile.txt");
```

since the default is to overwrite, either should work.

based on your edit just change the true to false, or remove it, in the FileWriter. The 2nd parameter is not required and when true specifies that you want to append data to the file.

You mentioned a problem of incomplete writes... BufferedWriter() isn't required, if your file is smallish then you can use FileWriter() by itself and avoid any such issues. If you do use BufferedWriter() you need to .flush() it before you .close() it.

```
BufferedWriter out1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("inValues.txt"));
for(String key: inout.keySet())
   {
       String val = inout.get(key);
       out1.write(key+" , "+val+"\n");
   }
   out1.flush();
   out1.close();
```

Comment: @andy but when i remove the second parameter i am getting incomplete data,becoz of some loops

Comment: @IYAZ.F You don't need me. You got 3 experts helping you. They'll help you figure it out, that I'm sure of it.

Comment: @IYAZ.F I edited my answer to provide you with code that should work for you. including the required out1.flush()

Answer (score 1):

Set append parameter to `false`

```
new FileWriter(yourFileLocation,false);
```

Comment: How can you be so sure OP is using `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: There is `java.io.FileWriter`.

Comment: @johnchen902 how can you be so sure about `FileWriter`..either way you have to set append parameter to false;

Comment: @anirudh but when i does appending false some contents are not coming

Comment: @IYAZ.F you have to `flush` the stream..call the `flush` method before closing stream

Comment: @Anirudh Api Docs of `Writer.close` said: "Closes the stream, flushing it first."

Comment: @IYAZ.F could you show us the keyset content and the output you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple File and FileWriter Class.
The Constructor of FileWrite Class provides 2 different varieties to make a file. One which only takes the Object of file. and another is with two parameters one with file object and second is boolean true/false which indicates whether file to be created is going to be append the contents or overwriting.

following code will do the overwriting of content.

```
public class WriteFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file= new File("new.txt");
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);
        try {

            fw.write("This is first line");
            fw.write("This is second line");
            fw.write("This is third line");
            fw.write("This is fourth line");
            fw.write("This is fifth line");

            fw.write("hello");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It works same with PrintWriter class also, since it also provides 2 different varieties of Constructors same as FileWriter. But you can always refer to Java Doc API.